# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined on click of button

Tags: c#

this code was working properly on click of addToCartButton button i just write some code on its master page and it started giving error hopefully after that

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

My code:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="pnladdCart" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="MainLoadingPanel">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <asp:Label ID="buyingErrorAlertMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="Error"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLocations" CssClass="boldgreen" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblValidFor" CssClass="boldgreen" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </div> <a href="javascript:void()">
                                <div class="link_button">
                                    <div class="link_button_left">
                                    </div>
                                    <asp:Button ID="addToCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" CssClass="link_button_middle"
                                        OnClick="addToCartButton_Click" />
                                    <div class="link_button_right">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>

</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

i just added this code to the  master page

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceNew" ConnectionString="<% $ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices  %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] from   tblGiftVouchers ORDER BY [Name]" runat="server">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
      <telerik:RadComboBox CssClass=".RadComboBoxCustomized" ID="RadsearchBox" DropDownCssClass="open-shopping-items"
                        AllowCustomText="true" CollapseAnimation-Type="InOutBack" ExpandAnimation-Type="InOutBack"
                        Filter="StartsWith" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceNew" Width="212px" Height="270px"
                        DataTextField="Name" EmptyMessage="Click Here Search By Keyword" runat="server">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: `this code was working..` what code?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined on click of button` is a js error. Post the js code.

Comment: This error didn't occur due to js code m adding this control to my master page in such aa way
       ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).RadAjaxManager.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(addToCartButton, ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).ItemsCount);
                ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).RadAjaxManager.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(addToCartButton, ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).ShoppingCartListContainer);

if i will not use this part of code on  pageload then it again works perfectly.

Comment: That specific error did occur due to js code. It is a js error message. What did you add to the masterpage?